# Building a Timeline from Lossy Time Stamps

Tags: c++, time, udp, lidar

I'm working with a product from Velodyne called the VLP-16 (the manual is available from their website with details) and I'm trying to build a timeline of the data it sends. The data it sends comes through a UDP transmission (UDP packets may appear out of order) and each packet is time-stamped with a 32-bit microsecond value. The microsecond value is synced with UTC time. This means that the timestamp will wrap around back to zero after each hour in UTC time. Since UDP packets may technically appear out of order, it is difficult to know what hour a packet may belong to.

Here's a snippet of code that generally describes the problem at hand:

```cpp
struct LidarPacket
{
  uint32_t microsecond;

  /* other data */
};

struct LidarTimelineEntry
{
  uint32_t hour;
  LidarPacket packet;
};

using LidarTimeline = std::vector<LidarTimelineEntry>;

void InsertAndSort(LidarTimeline& timeline, uint32_t hour, const LidarPacket&);

void OnLidarPacket(LidarTimeline &timeline, LidarPacket& newestPacket)
{
  /* Where to insert 'newestPacket'? */
}
```

The simplest approach would be to assume that the packets come in order.

```cpp
void OnLidarPacket(LidarTimeline &timeline, LidarPacket& newestPacket)
{
  if (timeline.empty()) {
    timeline.emplace_back(LidarTimelineEntry{0, newestPacket});
    return;
  }

  auto &lastEntry = timeline.back();

  if (newestPacket.microsecond < lastEntry.packet.microsecond) {
    InsertAndSort(timeline, lastEntry.hour + 1, newestPacket);
  } else {
    InsertAndSort(timeline, lastEntry.hour, newestPacket);
  }
}
```

This approach will fail if even one packet is out of order though. A slightly more robust way is to also check to see if the wrap occurs near the end of the hour.

```cpp
bool NearEndOfHour(const LidarPacket& lidarPacket)
{
  const uint32_t packetDuration = 1344; // <- approximate duration of one packet.

  const uint32_t oneHour = 3600000000; // <- one hour in microseconds

  return (lidarPacket.microsecond < packetDuration) || (lidarPacket.microsecond > (oneHour - packetDuration));
}

void OnLidarPacket(LidarTimeline &timeline, LidarPacket& newestPacket)
{
  if (timeline.empty()) {
    timeline.emplace_back(LidarTimelineEntry{0, newestPacket});
    return;
  }

  auto &lastEntry = timeline.back();

  if ((newestPacket.microsecond < lastEntry.packet.microsecond) && NearEndOfHour(lastEntry.packet)) {
    InsertAndSort(timeline, lastEntry.hour + 1, newestPacket);
  } else {
    InsertAndSort(timeline, lastEntry.hour, newestPacket);
  }
}
```

But it's difficult to tell if this is really going to cut it. What is the best way to build a multi-hour timeline from microsecond-stamped data coming from a UDP stream?

*Doesn't have to be answered in C++*

Comment: Define a window of time around your programs current UTC time say 10 mins before and ahead.  Throw away packets that do not appear in the window.  Assign packets that do appear in the window to the correct hour.  The time-window defines the maximum time a UDP packet can reasonably be delayed and also allows for clock drift between sender and receiver.  You can improve this using sliding and/or variable size window depending on how reliable the UDP stream is.

Comment: @RichardCritten I like this approach. One question, though. The UTC time window would have to be defined in terms of seconds and microseconds (otherwise, a time window near the hour boundary would overflow). How do you compare a microsecond time stamp to a full sec/usec time stamp? The only way I can think of doing it is to capture the time that the packet was received in, and attaching the `secs` to the `usec` of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I ended up going with is the following:

1. If the timeline is empty, add the time point to the timeline with `hour=0`
2. Otherwise, create three possible time points. One using the hour of the last time point, one with an hour before the hour of the last time point, and the last an hour after the last time point.
3. Compute the absolute differences of all these time points with the last time point (using a 64-bit integer).
4. Select the hour which yields the smallest absolute difference with the last time point.

This approach passed the following tests:

```cpp
uint32_t inputTimes[] = { 0, 750, 250 };
// gets sorted to:
uint32_t outputTimes[] = { 0, 250, 750 };
int32_t outputHours[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

```cpp
uint32_t inputTimes[] = { 1500, oneHour - 500, 250 };
// gets sorted to:
uint32_t outputTimes[] = { oneHour - 500, 250, 1500 };
int32_t outputHours[] = { -1, 0, 0 };
```

```cpp
uint32_t inputTimes[] = { oneHour - 500, 1500, 250 };
// gets sorted to:
uint32_t outputTimes[] = { oneHour - 500, 250, 1500 };
int32_t outputHours[] = { 0, 1, 1 };
```